# Plot is not defined when using it in eval()

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, eval, observable-plot

I have a notebook project that uses React and ObservablePlot and react-monaco
there's an IDE on my App that :

1. takes the User Code ( Observable Code )  like this `Plot.lineY(props.data, { x: "Date", y: "Close" })`
2. then I pass that code as a prop to my Component
3. then I pass that prop string code to the eval

#### the error that I faced with

Plot is not defined ReferenceError: Plot is not defined

---

#### What I want:

is to Compile that code with eval and put the return value to marks of the Observable plot.

OR

somehow convert user string code to JS readable code

---

Plot is an npm package so i imported it from its package like below

Here is my Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import * as Plot from "@observablehq/plot";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const PlotChart = (props) => {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    d3.csv("/gistemp.csv", d3.autoType).then(setData);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data === undefined) return;
    const plot = Plot.plot({
      marks: [eval(props.plot)],
    });
    containerRef.current.append(plot);
    return () => plot?.remove();
  }, [data]);

  return <div ref={containerRef} />;
};

export default PlotChart;
```

I searched a lot and I got no answer for this Problem. Any guide will be appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys for anyone who might face with same problem.

It looks like the eval can't use the imported Package; instead, you can store it in a variable that is declared in the same scope that the eval gets used.
then use that variable name in the string code that you want to pass into eval.

```
const PlotChart = (props) => {
 const containerRef = useRef();
 const [data, setData] = useState();
 
 const compileCode = () => {
    // store package in a variable
    const plotly = Plot;
    return eval(props.plot);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    compileCode();
    setData(props.data);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data === undefined) return;
    const plot = Plot.plot({
      marks: [compileCode()],
    });
    containerRef.current.append(plot);
    return () => plot?.remove();
  }, [data]);

  return <div ref={containerRef} />;
};

export default PlotChart;
```

now if you pass a string like below your eval will work fine.

```
plotly.lineY(props.data, {x: 'Date', y: 'Close'})
```